# Failed to create driver Failed to install browsers, exit code: 1 when playwright Java is tried to run via BrowserStack on firewalled Jenkins server

Tags: java, playwright, playwright-java

I get below issue in a company owned Jenkins Server when I tried to build Playwright Java code  which runs via chromium bowser in BrowserStack.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create driver
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to install browsers, exit code: 1
```

My code is below.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.microsoft.playwright.*;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class LaunchBrowserInBrowserStack {

    final String BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME = "myusername";
    final String BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY = "myaccesskey";
    Playwright playwright;
    Browser browser;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


        JsonObject capabilitiesObject = new JsonObject();
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("browser", "chrome");    
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("browser_version", "latest");
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("os", "windows");
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("os_version", "10");
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("name", "Playwright in browserstack");
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("build", "playwright-java-5");
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("project", "APP Automation Project"); //This will create a project in BrowserStack UI, so easy to organize.
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("browserstack.username", BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME);
        capabilitiesObject.addProperty("browserstack.accessKey", BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY);

        playwright = Playwright.create();
        BrowserType chromium = playwright.chromium();
        String caps = URLEncoder.encode(capabilitiesObject.toString(), "utf-8");
        String ws_endpoint = "wss://cdp.browserstack.com/playwright?caps=" + caps;
        browser = chromium.connect(ws_endpoint);

    }
```

This is the shell command that I used to build it .

```
mvn clean test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=TestSuites/DemoTestPlan.xml
```

Is adding install chromium via below command, will solve this issue ? because I couldn't try it due to below set of different errors.

```
mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="install chromium"

/tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node)
/tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node)
/tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node)
/tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node)
/tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node)
/tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /tmp/playwright-java-7544179260710857064/node)
```

Comment: Your error message reads that there is an issue with the Firewall. 

For your tests to run via Jenkins tests on the host machine please ensure to whitelist the traffic for *.browserstack.com (Wildcard) and on port 80 and port 443.

Comment: Switched from Centos 7 to Amazon Linux 2023 Jenkins node , solved the issue.

Comment: New node had GLIBC_2.27